# ¿Como uso un formato distinto en la fecha guardada MongoDB usando Moment?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs

Estoy tratando de mostrar en la vista una tabla con elementos con fechas en el formato DD-MM-AAAA hh:mm

hago un GET a la ruta:

```
routeCtrl.all = async(req, res) => {

    const books = await Book.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('author', 'name phone');

    await res.render('all-books', { books });
};
```

Los resultados que envío a la vista dentro del objeto "books" se muestran como:

```
[ { _id: 5d9575cdc31c0e10c83fcb41,
    notas: 'Otra nota',
    motivo: 'Estudio',
    Date: 2019-10-03T04:15:09.720Z,
    user: 5d9574bcc31c0e10c83fcb3b,
    author:
     { _id: 5d957509c31c0e10c83fcb3c,
       name: 'Miguel Marroquin Jordan',
       phone: '40009374' },
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5d9575cdc31c0e10c83fcb41,
    notas: 'Sin Notas',
    motivo: 'Diversion',
    Date: 2019-11-03T04:14:09.720Z,
    user: 3e9564b631c0e10c20349cb,
    author:
     { _id: 5e95509c231c0e10c83fcbb5,
       name: 'Jose',
       phone: '44322374' },
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Lo que busco es cambiar el formato

> "Date: 2019-11-03T04:14:09.720Z"

por

> "Date: 03-11-2019 4:14pm"

utilizando moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `momentjs`, podemos [parsear la fecha](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/) en la propiedad `Date` directamente y luego indicar [el formato de salida](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) que necesitamos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let notas = [{
  _id: '5d9575cdc31c0e10c83fcb41',
  notas: 'Otra nota',
  motivo: 'Estudio',
  Date: '2019-10-03T04:15:09.720Z',
  user: '5d9574bcc31c0e10c83fcb3b',
  author: {
    _id: '5d957509c31c0e10c83fcb3c',
    name: 'Miguel Marroquin Jordan',
    phone: '40009374'
  },
  __v: 0
}, {
  _id: '5d9575cdc31c0e10c83fcb41',
  notas: 'Sin Notas',
  motivo: 'Diversion',
  Date: '2019-11-03T04:14:09.720Z',
  user: '3e9564b631c0e10c20349cb',
  author: {
    _id: '5e95509c231c0e10c83fcbb5',
    name: 'Jose',
    phone: '44322374'
  },
  __v: 0
}];

notas.forEach(nota => {
  let fecha = moment.utc(nota.Date).format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mma');
  nota.Date = fecha;
});
console.log(notas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Esto me da como resultado todas las fechas, lo que quiero es obtener un objeto con el resto de items (_id, notas, motivo, Date, User, author.name, author.phone) pero con la fecha en el formato adecuado, como reemplazo Date con el resultado de "fecha" para poder enviarlo a la vista?

Comment: Hola @MiguelAngelMarroquinJordan, es un ejemplo de cómo podes lograr lo que planteaste en tu pregunta. Con respecto a este nuevo escenario que planteas, lograr dicho resultado es tan simple como asignar `fecha` a una propiedad de `nota`. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: la linea "nota.Date = fecha;" parece no funcionar, agregue un "console.log();" antes de esa linea y me da el resultado correcto: "05-10-2019 04:01" pero en el "console.log(nota.Date);" despues de esa linea me da "2019-10-05T04:01:23.718Z" como si no estuviese asignando el valor de "fecha" a "nota.Date", a que crees que se deba? estoy trayendo los datos desde una DB en Mongo utilizando:

Comment: @MiguelAngelMarroquinJordan necesitaria ver el código en cuestión. Evidentemente estas teniendo un problema entre el objeto modificado y resultante. En mi respuesta puedes ver que dicho comportamiento no ocurre.

Comment: estoy obteniendo la data desde una base de datos de MongoDB utilizando: `const notes = await Note.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('author', 'name phone');`

Comment: si le doy console.log(notes); justo debajo de donde obtengo la data, me da la data que agregue arriba en mi pregunta.

Comment: y este es el codigo de mi "Modelo" ; `const NoteSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    motivo: { type: String },
    notas: { type: String },
    Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

});

// Exportar el esquema
module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', NoteSchema);`

Comment: @MiguelAngelMarroquinJordan no veo en que parte del código estas usando moment para modificar el formato de la fecha

Comment: despues de recibir la data: `const notes = await Note.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('author', 'name phone');` utilizo el codigo con el que me estas ayudando: `notas.forEach(nota => {
  let fecha = moment.utc(nota.Date).format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mma');
  nota.Date = fecha;
});
console.log(notas);` agregando los console log. crees que podria ser por el formato en el que viene la data de MongoDB , segun veo viene en formato ISODate , y despues deberia de transformarla y agregarla como String o me equivoco? si intento agregarla como ISODate da lo mismo correcto?

Comment: @MiguelAngelMarroquinJordan, intenta cambiar `const notes` por `let notes`. Diría que el formato de fechas no es el problema

Comment: Tuve que hacer lo siguiente: agregue un nuevo campo a mi modelo de mongoose que se llama "dateToShow: {type: String}" y en el codigo que me compartiste agregue lo siguiente `onst notes = await Note.find({ user: req.user.id }).populate('author', 'name phone');

    notes.forEach(note => {
        const fecha = moment(note.Date).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
        notes[notes.indexOf(note)].dateToShow = fecha;
    });

    console.log(notes);`al parecer esta tratando el objeto como un "array" por lo que hay que indicar el "index" y despues asignar el valor como string para poder mostrarlo